# Nested Areas in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am interesting to define some nested Areas Is there any possible way? And whats your suggestion about this implementation?

Comment: Whats the reason for this? I cant think of a valid reason for doing this?

Comment: @Pino Actually we work on a big mvc project with a lot of categories and sub-projects this is very good we can use Areas, but also we need something to implement our sub-projects in it, something like nested Areas. I think in team working this way can be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such notion exist in ASP.NET MVC. If your project is really that big that it requires *nested areas* for separating some logic, you might consider splitting your application into multiple applications.